# I would like the values I enter inside the cells of the column to be automatically transformed into negative google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

```js
function newColumn_U() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    targetSheet.insertColumnAfter(targetSheet.getLastColumn());
    var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange(1,targetSheet.getLastColumn()+1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('d/M/yyyy - U');
}
```

I created a code that creates a new column on google sheet to manage the outputs. The name of the column is `today's date - U` (issued in Italian). I would like the values I enter inside the cells of the column to be automatically transformed into negative.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by `automatically transformed into negative` you mean transforming a positive number into a negative one (and not vice versa), and that the column to look for is the last column with content in your sheet, you could use a simple `onEdit` trigger for this, so that any number that a user adds to this column is turned negative:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e.range;
  const value = e.value;  
  const lastColumn = range.getSheet().getLastColumn();
  if (!Number.isNaN(value) && value > 0 && range.getColumn() === lastColumn && range.getRow() > 1) {
    range.setValue(-value);
  }
}
```

This script uses the `event object` to check whether:

- The edited value is a number, using [Number.isNaN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN).
- The number is positive.
- The edited column is the last one in the row.
- The edited row is not the header.

#### Update:

If you want to do this for all columns whose header include `- U`, you can do this instead:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e ? e.range : SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveRange();
  const value = e ? e.value : range.getValue();
  const colIndex = range.getColumn();
  const header = range.getSheet().getRange(1,colIndex).getDisplayValue();
  if (!Number.isNaN(value) && value > 0 && header.toString().includes("- U") && range.getRow() > 1) {
    range.setValue(-value);
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [onEdit trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)
- [Event objects: Edit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Comment: Iamblichus thank you. The code works but is it possible to put only negative columns that have header with words "- U"?

Comment: @lamblichus can you help me?

Comment: @FrancescoDiMicco Take a look at the `Update` section of my answer.

Comment: @lamblichus gives me problems with e.range ->TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined

Comment: @FrancescoDiMicco That's because you are trying to fire the function directly from the editor. It's an onEdit trigger, it's supposed to run when the spreadsheet is edited by the user, not via script editor.

Comment: Owned by: me
Deployment: head
Event: from spreadsheet - on edit
Function: oneEdit
Select event type: on edit

Comment: @FrancescoDiMicco Not sure I understand what you mean with your last comment. In any case, I updated my last code snippet so that it works both when editing the spreadsheet and when executing it directly from the script editor.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to run your new script with editor and it works but in google sheet the values remain positive.

Comment: @FrancescoDiMicco This is working for me, please make sure you didn't make any change to the function I provided.

Comment: i copied your code again and now this happens: TypeError: header.includes is not a function

Comment: @FrancescoDiMicco This might mean the header of the edited column (that is, the first row) is not a string. Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information) so that I can try reproduce this?

Comment: @FrancescoDiMicco In any case, you could try doing `header.toString().includes("- U")` in order to make sure you have a string. Check my updated code snippet.

Comment: Does not work. I create the new column like this:
var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange (1, targetSheet.getLastColumn () + 1) .setValue (new Date ()). setNumberFormat ('d / M / yyyy - U');}

Comment: I cannot share files because I have company restrictions. I can't even share a fake one

Comment: @FrancescoDiMicco Oh I see, the `- U` is displayed, but just as a format, it's not actual cell content, so it won't be retrieved by `getValue()`. In order to fix this, use `getDisplayValue()` instead of `getValue()` when retrieving `header`, like this `const header = range.getSheet().getRange(1,colIndex).getDisplayValue();` (already updated in my answer). See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getDisplayValue()

Comment: great, it works great now. Thank you so much